# `magit-tag-release` error: "Invalid version syntax: '0.7-5'"

Tags: magit

I'm unable to tag releases with current Magit from Elpa.  Doing:

t RET r (`magit-tag-release`)

I immediately get the error message: "Invalid version syntax: '0.7-5'" in the minibuffer.

This happens either from the magit-log buffer or the main magit buffer.

Below is partial output from `git tag`:

```
release-0.7-5
release-0.7-6
release-0.7-7
release-0.7-8
release-0.7-9
```

which shows the naming pattern of my release tags.  Any pointers welcome.

Answer (score 1):

That's due to a recent regression, introduced by pull-request [#4075)](https://github.com/magit/magit/pull/4075).  At the bottom [d27d6e4678](https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/d27d6e467857ed4a78c7cf7d609561df789e2a6c) is mentioned, which fixes this.

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait for this update.  I also noticed that if I try to tag a particular commit from the log buffer, the tag is always created at the latest commit instead of where point is at.  Is this the expected behaviour?  I realize it might be a separate issue, but I vaguely remember it was possible to tag a commit from the log buffer.